# Sometimes BottomSheetDialogFragment opens in center of screen like alert dialog

Tags: android, android-bottomsheetdialog, bottomsheetdialogfragment

I have BottomSheetDialogFragment which required to open in expanded state and should skip collapsed state while swipedown.

The problem is, I get unexpected behavior sometimes

[image: Unexpected Behavior]

Why I am getting this kind of view sometimes?

here below is my code for that,

```
@Override
    public int getTheme() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 21) {
            return R.style.BottomSheetDialogTheme;
        } else {
            return super.getTheme();
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        BottomSheetDialog dialog = (BottomSheetDialog) super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

        dialog.setOnShowListener((DialogInterface.OnShowListener) dialog1 -> {
            BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog1;
            FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) d.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
            if (bottomSheet != null) {
                BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setSkipCollapsed(true);
                BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setFitToContents(true);
                BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setPeekHeight(1000);
            }
        });

        return dialog;
    }
```

And style/theming for the same is

```
     <style name="BottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="BaseBottomSheetDialog">
            <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@android:color/transparent
            </item>
        </style>
        <!-- set the rounded drawable as background to your bottom sheet -->
        <style name="BottomSheet" parent="@style/Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
            <item name="android:background">@drawable/bottomsheet_round_corner_bg</item>
        </style>
    
        <style name="BaseBottomSheetDialog" parent="@style/Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
            <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
            <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheet</item>
            <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
        </style>
```

Mostly I achieve this part but somehow other screenshot behavior appears.
[image: Expected Behavior]

Anyone have solve or faced this issue can comment or answer solution,
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe need to add **window.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM).**

Comment: Its bottomsheet, shouldn't it be bottom by default?

Comment: BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setPeekHeight(1000); You used this, I have seen an answer that says to set the height to set Gravity.BOTTOM according the source code, but I have no time to see source code, you can look at the source code of onCreatView.